# Any database with all of companies previous CEO's?

Tags: data, historical-data, fundamentals, database

I'm doing some research on CEO's and company chairmen and I'm looking for a database that contains this data for all the public US companies. The data needs dates associated with the names as well. I'll give an example of what I'm looking for.

- CompanyName, CeoName, StartDate,      EndDate
- Company A       , Name1     , 12/04/2000, 10/17/2015
- Company A       , Name2     , 10/18/2015, currently active
- Company B       , Name3     , 05/10/2005, currently active

Not sure if the SEC provides this info or not. SEC filings mostly just get confusing for me so I might not be looking in the right place. If no database like this exists I guess I'll have to spend the next couple of weeks manually scraping wikipedia for this.

Comment: How about [permid](https://permid.org/)?

Comment: @hroptatyr I hadn't heard of them before, I will look into it if it's priced reasonably.

Comment: Well, it's open and free, so I guess that counts as reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SEC's EDGAR system has this.  Companies are required to file a [form 8-K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_8-K) to notify investors of events within a company that may be important.  A CEO being replaced is one of those events, generally under item 5.02 in the 8-K.

For example, on August 3rd, 2020 Clorox (NYSE: CLX) replaced their CEO.  Here is a link to their filings: [CLX EDGAR filings](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=0000021076&action=getcompany).  Go to the August 3rd 8-K, click document, click the link next to Current Report.  You will find item 5.02 with the info.  Another example would be Disney (NYSE: DIS).  You can find the filing here: [Disney 8-K 2020-02-25](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1744489/000174448920000054/0001744489-20-000054-index.htm)

Comment: Ok, this will require some scraping but it should be what I want.

Comment: @tysonu it will but the Edgar site is laid out in a way that is pretty easy to crawl through with a spider using a python library like scrapy.

Comment: Yes, shouldn't be to hard to scrape with python. It seems as though someone also built an API wrapper for SEC filings over at sec-api.io I'm still going to need to manually extract the information I need from the 8-k. It don't seem like there is any set structure that is used so it's likely not possible to programmatically extract the names I need.